# Sort the stocks list in status screen alphabetically

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When you go to the stocks list in status menu (z -> Stocks) the first column is ordered in a very weird and unpredictable way.

Is it somehow possible to have it sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Sadly, to the best of my knowledge no.

Comment: there is no such option, but to find a specific item a search function is provided.

Answer (score 1):

The [DFHack plugin](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=118001.0) (and possibly the vanilla game) allows searching/filtering for specific terms in many of the DF screen lists, including Stocks, Caravan Trade, Stockpile, Animals, Military assignments, Announcements, Job list, etc. So you could just search for the letter 'A' and look at all of those items, then do the same down the alphabet.